# how to validate a selectbox in a table angular js

Tags: angularjs, validation

on ng-repeat in my table multiple slectboxes are loaded,how do i validate each selectbox seperately? with the following the validation is binding all the selectboxes,if i select one box all the other boxes validations gets turned off.

```
 $scope.Module.Save1 = function (ngForm) {

        if (ngForm.$invalid) {

            $scope.invalidSubmitAttempt = true;
            return;
        }

    $scope.module.Save();
}
```

html

```
 <tr  id="TableBody" ng-repeat="id in IDS.IDSDetails">
             <td><select id="selectbox" name="selectbox" ng-model="id.CategoryID"   ng-options="" ng-click="id.Status=false" ng-required="!id.status">
                <option selected disabled value="">-- select--</option></select>
            <span style="color:red;" class="validation-error" ng-show="(myForm.selectbox.$dirty || invalidSubmitAttempt) && myForm.selectbox.$error.required ">*Required</span>

            </td>   
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!. just have to add a new form to your table

```
 <td ng-form="form1"><select id="selectbox" name="selectbox" ng-model="id.CategoryID"   ng-options="" ng-click="id.Status=false" ng-required="!id.status">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- select--</option></select>
        <span style="color:red;" class="validation-error" ng-show="(Form1.selectbox.$dirty || invalidSubmitAttempt) && Form1.selectbox.$error.required ">*Required</span>

        </td>
```

you do this because you have validation outside the table, therefore you add a sperate form.